# Merging two audio files which is in sdcard

Tags: android, audio, merge

Hi have recorded audio and store it in sdcard. I have a resume activity which starts recording after a stop,but I need to pause the recording and start from where i stops(append both the previous one and new recorded audio). How can i append the newly recorded audio each time i resume, thus i get a complete audio while playing.

Comment: Hi Manikandan, i also facing the problem with merging audio. i have tried in two different ways first is using media recording i could not merge two MP4 or 3gp file. so i moved to second way using Audio Recorder in this case the resultant file is very large and i could not compress it. Have you got the solution? please help me to compress or merge the file. i am also from madurai.

Comment: You can record audio to files using AudioRecorder. This will give you audio files in raw PCM format. You can merge them together. But resulting file is not going to be playable. You'll need to add correct WAV header at the beginning of that file to make it playable.

Comment: i did also convert it into wav format by told in the site http://matrix-examplecode.blogspot.in/2011/12/audio-recording-part-2.html but it takes large size. i tried different sample rate it reduce the size but quality is too low. if i use 44100 audio quality is good but size is very large. how to reduce the size? how did you finish? please help me.